# How to iterate through a 2d array with thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have a sudoku generator class that returns a 9x9 sudoku board as a double array (int), I'm trying to loop through the array and create a table but I'm stuck and I couldn't find any information on the Thymeleaf website.

**UPDATE**

Got it working thanks to @Nikolas

```
<form  id="sudokuBoard" method="post">
        <table class="table table-dark">
            <tr th:each="row: ${board}">
                <td th:each="value: ${row}">
                    <div th:switch="${value}">
                        <input th:case="0" style="width:30px;height:30px;text-align:center" type = "text" maxlength="1" value="0">
                        <input th:case="*" style="width:30px;height:30px;text-align:center;background-color:lightgreen" type = "text" th:value="${value}" readonly>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <input type="submit"> Check Solution </input>
    </form>
```

Comment: can you give some code? to see how it is written your 2d array?

Comment: How is this "too broad"? Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 5):

Use 2 nested `th:each` commands:

```
<table>
    <tr th:each="i: ${array}">
        <td th:each="item: ${j}">
            <span th:text="${item}"></span >
        </td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can transform 2d array to single array like this :

```
int k = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
   {
      single_array[k++] = twoD_array[i][j];
   }
}
```